# Arrangement of Blocks to fill an Area

Tags: combinatorics

I have a $14$ by $17$ rectangle. This has area of $238$ units squared. I have $28$ smaller rectangular blocks that I want to fit into the larger $14$ by $17$ rectangle. This means each rectangular block will have area $8.5$.

My question is: how do I arrange these $28$ smaller rectangular blocks to cover the larger rectangle.

The dimensions of the smaller rectangular blocks are 5 by 1.7 by the way.

Comment: Please share your efforts.

Comment: @AndreasLenz Taking $14$ to be height of larger rectangle with $17$ units wide. I can arrange $10$ smaller blocks of width $1.7$ and height $5$ horizontally if that makes sense. I can have $2$ rows of this, giving $20$ blocks. I then have $4$ units height and $17$ units width left to cover. If I change the orientation of my smaller blocks, I can have $2$ more rows of $3$ blocks. That is $26$ blocks, leaving the only area where rectangles can be fitted of a width of $2$ and height $4$. I can't fit any more blocks, so I only have $26$ but I want $28$

Comment: That's a good start. Hint: Maybe try to think about how to partition the other (length 14) side into units of 5 and 1.7

Comment: @AndreasLenz Maybe go for $2$ lots of $5$ and $2$ lots of $1.7$? I will try something like that now. Is there a formula / algorithm to solve this ? As in, if I give any dimensions of the larger block and the smaller blocks and the number of smaller blocks to solve this ?

Comment: I am not aware of an algorithm that solves this, but there might surely be one. In this case, I was just thinking about partitioning the side lengths of the large rectangle with side length of the smaller ones.

Comment: @AndreasLenz Okay thank you. So a bit like trial and error right